# Why I cannot change my DNS in settings?

Tags: dns

In settings but can do that in control panel

[image]

[image]
In the picture, in IP settings, I set IPv4DNS server to 23.21.43.50

Yet below, in properties, the IPv4 DNS server is still 192.168.1.1

Why?

That's not the right place to change it?

So what actually "changed" into 23.21.43.50?

In what way what I do is different than the method here
http://support.smartdnsproxy.com/customer/portal/articles/2092782-windows-10-setup-for-smart-dns-proxy

Comment: You set your adapter DNS settings, your router’s dns Settings are something else entirely, why are you setting your dns server?  Log into the Administrator configuration page for your router and change the dns server for the router.  The process is extremely easy there isn’t any documentation I can provide.  **Check your router documentation for more information**

Comment: That's what I wanna do. I want to change DNS settings of my wifi adapter

Comment: I want the DNS to work only on my computer not on my whole network

Comment: - If that is your case.  What is your question?  You have already done that.

Comment: No I don't. Actually the instruction in http://support.smartdnsproxy.com/customer/portal/articles/2092782-windows-10-setup-for-smart-dns-proxy works. What I did didn't work. I don't know why. I think both should work.

Comment: Your link does not actually work.